# VST plugins for creating surrounding environments effects on voice overs

Tags: vst, plugins, voice-over, production-audio

Is there any good VST plugins free or paid versions which creates surrounding environments effect to voice-over track?

Example, when i use this plugin on the voice-over tack it should give me options to create effects like inside the room, hall, inside car, talking through phone / walkie-talkie etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a product called "Speakerphone" from "Audioease". This has some basic room reverbs and also device impulses. Additional - more expensive - options are "Altiverb" and "Indoor" - also by Audioease.